ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow / Cygwin
I'm trying to install Tensorflow on Cygwin but i'm getting these Errors :
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.12.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.12.0

$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

What im using:

Windows10

Cygwin last version

Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Python 3.7.12 (default, Nov 23 2021, 18:58:07)
[GCC 11.2.0] on Cygwin


How to fix it ?
i tried to upgrade PIP but nothing and got this (note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.)

i tried that yes but it didn't work

Can you install any other packages so we can rule out cygwin configuration issue?

i installed all the necessary packages normally on Cygwin and installed Numpy and it worked but idk what's the issue with TensorFlow specifically

It seems you're trying to install tensorflow 2.12.0 to python 3.7.0. According to release notes of tensorflow 2.12.0. It says that

Support for Python 3.7 has been removed. We are not releasing any more patches for Python 3.7.

I would suggest to upgrade python or downgrade tensorflow.
